# CustomAnalyser Lucene Connector GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

I'm having issues figuring out how to specify my own analyzer implementation inside of GraphDB. After reading through the [documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/full-text-search.html) and a couple of other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517064/how-to-create-a-custom-analyzerfactory-in-graphdb-full-text-search), I seem to be running into issues with .jar dependencies.

In order to build the boilerplate `CustomAnalyzer` and `CustomAnalyzerFactory` classes, I had to use the `lucene.jar` and `lucene-core.jar` located in `lib/plugins/lucene`. My gradle build file looks like this:

```
group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/lucene', include: '*.jar')

}
```

**Note: `libs/lucene` is the folder in my gradle project where I copied the `lucene.jar` and `lucene-core.jar` located in `lib/plugins/lucene` of the graphdb stand-alone server distribution**

After I compile  the code  and create the jar file using `gradle clean jar`, I copy it into `lib/plugins/lucene-connector`.

I restart graph-db, go into connectors and attempt to add a lucene-connector using the UI. I manage to get all the way down to where you can specify your analyzer. However when I specify com.example.CustomAnalyzer, I get the following error message.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter
```

After some digging around, I've found that there are 2 lucene-core.jar files. One in `libs/plugins/lucene` and the other in `libs/plugins/lucene-connector`. The `lucene-core.jar` in `libs/plugins/lucene-connector` does not have the `ASCIIFoldingFilter` class.

I've even tried creating a fatJar w/ all the dependencies contained in a single jar, but when I do that graphdb fails to load any of the connectors.

Not really sure, where I'm going wrong, have a feeling its got something to do with how I'm building and referencing the jar files.

---

I also tried removing the ASCIIFilter from the CustomAnalyzer but get a whole new set of errors:

```
Caused by: com.ontotext.trree.sdk.BadRequestException: Unable to instantiate analyzer class, only analyzers with a default constructor or a constructor accepting single Version parameter are possible: com.example.CustomAnalyzer
    at com.ontotext.trree.plugin.externalsync.impl.lucene4.CreateAnalyzerUtil.instantiateAnalyzer(CreateAnalyzerUtil.java:70)
    at com.ontotext.trree.plugin.externalsync.impl.lucene4.CreateAnalyzerUtil.createAnalyzerFromClassName(CreateAnalyzerUtil.java:42)
    at com.ontotext.trree.plugin.externalsync.impl.lucene4.Lucene4ExternalStore.open(Lucene4ExternalStore.java:182)
    at com.ontotext.trree.plugin.externalsync.impl.lucene4.Lucene4ExternalStore.initImpl(Lucene4ExternalStore.java:718)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

GraphDB offers two mechanisms for full text searching. The first option is GraphDB [Lucene Connector plugin](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/lucene-graphdb-connector.html), which is the recommended approach for any new development. The other alternative is the [GraphDB FTS plugin](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/full-text-search.html) that is using a slightly different indexing approach. Its main limitation due the nature of the index is the lack of automatic synchronisation when the RDF data changes.

In your example you want to extend the Lucene Connector, but actually modify the binary of the FTS plugin. To simplify the instructions and all necessary steps to develop, test and deploy the custom analyser, I have prepared a public project to try:

https://gitlab.ontotext.com/vassil.momtchev/custom-lucene-analyzer

Comment: To run in Docker: ```RUN set -e; \
    git clone https://gitlab.ontotext.com/vassil.momtchev/custom-lucene-analyzer.git; \
    cd custom-lucene-analyzer; \
    sed -i "s/<lucene.version>.*<\/lucene.version>/<lucene.version>7.7.0<\/lucene.version>/g" pom.xml; \
    apt update; \
    apt install -y maven;
ADD CustomAnalyzer.java src/main/java/com/ontotext/graphdb/lucene/CustomAnalyzer.java
RUN set -e; \
    cd custom-lucene-analyzer; \
    mvn install -DskipTests; \
    cp target/custom-lucene-analyzer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/graphdb/dist/lib/plugins/lucene-connector;```